# Remove row brackets after appending lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, append

l have a list as follow:

```
My_list=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]]
```

such that :

```
a=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and

```
b=[2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]
```

Then l append them as follow

```
My_list.append(a)
My_list.append(b)
```

l would like to transform it to :

```
 My_list=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]
```

How can l remove a and b brackets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
My_list=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]]
print(list(chain(*My_list)))
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `extend`:

```
My_list = []

a=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b=[2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]

My_list.extend(a)
My_list.extend(b)

My_list
#[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]
```

Otherwise you can flatten already created `list`:

```
My_list = [i for sublist in My_list for i in sublist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
My_list = a[:]
My_list.extends(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b=[2, 5, 8, 11, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 7, 1]
```

## Python 2.7

```
new_list = a + b
```

## Python 3.6

```
new_list = [*a,*b]
```